# Test condition for visibility check in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility

I'd like to know if there's a test conditions using which one can check the visibility state(hidden or visible) of a  tag.

I mean a test condition,which could be used with the if() statement.

thanks!

Comment: You should mention you where using jQuery... Anyway IIRC the trick that jQuery makes behind the scenes, to verify the "visibility" of an element is simply to check that the element's `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties are greater than zero - with some quirks about `tr` elements I think -...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using jQuery then:

```
$('#id').is(':visible');
```

Comment: Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible (http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

In case you *don't* use jQuery this simple javascript condition should work:

```
if(document.getElementById("elementId").style.visibility=="visible"){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use jQuery and do `$('#id').is(':visible')`. Otherwise you'll be writing a function that doesn't work as well and isn't as nicely coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it's very easy:

```
if ($(SELECTOR).is(":visible")) {
  // do amazing things
}
```